# Is this transformation defined on a basis is a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let *V* be a vector space, and let {*a, b, c*} be a basis for *V*.

Define *T* : *V* → *V* as *a* ↦ 0, *b* ↦ *a*, *c* ↦ *a*.
Also define *T*(*x+y*) = *T*(*x*) + *T*(*y*) and *T*(*sx*) = *sT*(*x*), for any vectors *x*, *y* and scalar *s*.

Is *T* a linear map? If so, then shouldn't rank(*V*) + nullity(*V*) = dim(*V*)? But doesn't rank(*V*) = 1, nullity(*V*) = 1, and dim(*V*) = 3?

Please help, I am extremely confused.

Edit (what I asked in the comments): I thought that the nullity is the dimension of the null space, and the null space is the vectors that map to 0. So the basis of the null space is {a}, and the nullity is 1. However, b + (-c) maps to a + (-a) = 0, so would b and c be in the basis of the null space? Would that make the nullity 3? I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: The map is not yet defined on all vectors of $V$. How does it map $a+b$, for example?

Comment: Any map on a basis extends to a unique linear map.  So, the $T$ you've defined will be linear.

Comment: Ok, I clarified it, and I also added my main question I have about this thing

Comment: You should find that the nullity is $2$, not $1$.

Comment: Can you show me how to find it? Sorry, I am just now learning about this stuff and it is confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be Rank(T) + Nullity(T) = Dim(V)

Rank and nullity are the dimensions of the image space and kernel respectively with respect to a given linear operator.

If {a,b,c} is a basis for V, then so is {a, b - c, c}. Under this basis, you’ll see that the nullity is 2.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question!